# Flutter TextFormField TextCapitalization.words not working when text is selected

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

In my Flutter app, I use a simple `TextFormField`, as followed:

```
TextFormField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
),
```

Now let's say that, in the `TextFormField`, I entered: `Example`, and `ample` is selected (I actually use that for auto-completion. For example if the user enters `Ex`, so `ample` is automatically added, but selected so the user can continue typing).

Now, if at that moment, the user wants to type something, I expect the keyboard to remain in lowercase mode, since the user is about to enter a text without any space before.

Unfortunately it's not the case: as soon as a text is selected, even though it's in the middle of a word, the keyboard is in uppercase mode.

The result of that, for my auto-completion, is that if a suggestion is added after the cursor, every letter that the user enters is in uppercase (even though I defined `TextCapitalization.words`.

How can I fix that?

Thanks.